# Find DOM elements based on HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently looking for a way in which I can find a DOM element based on a supplied HTML string.
I have a string like

```
<div class="s-navigation s-navigation__muted s-navigation__sm" style=""></div>
```

where all of the children have been removed.
Using this string I would like to be able to find the corresponding DOM element in a document. I do't have access to the children as they took to much space to store too.

I've tried just parsing it in jQuery but the element doesn't exist - i assume because the innards have gone.

Thanks,

Comment: `document.querySelector('.s-navigation').innerHTML` will return the html contents inside the div. Is this what you are looking for?  If not please provide some code snippet

Comment: It's not specific to this html string, it could be any. I'm just retrieving these strings that I have previously stored and then trying to find them on the current webpage

Comment: In this day and age, you never need to use jQuery. You can simply use `document.querySelector[All?]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this

```js
var htmlString = '<div class="s-navigation s-navigation__muted s-navigation__sm" style="color: red"></div>';

function findByString(str){
  var tag = str.match(/^<(\S+)/)[1];
  var attrs = str.match(/([^\s="]+="[^"]+")|([^\s=']+='[^']+')/g);
  var q = tag+attrs.map(t => '['+t+']').join('');
  return document.querySelector(q);
}

var el = findByString(htmlString);
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="s-navigation s-navigation__muted s-navigation__sm" style="color: red">
<div id="some-child element"></div>
</div>
<div id="dont select me" style="color: beautiful"></div>
```

But honestly I not really understand why do you store them in this way, and not store the selector to find it (id or attribute list in the worse case)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll try this out tomorrow and report back. :)

Comment: I'm storing it like this, because the element im storing could be any element, some wont have id's, some wont have classes etc.